# Add-Migration : Exception calling "Start" with "1"

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

Add-Migration : Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS
platform."
At line:1 char:1

- Add-Migration addIdentity
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception,Add-Migration
  ```

I have this error when i try to add migration with new identity, before this i make some migrations and works. I search in google but i not see answer. Can someone help me?

Comment: Try add migration with developer command prompt `dotnet ef migrations add`

Comment: Yes, its works but not add user tables for identity.